# how to deny access to bot accessing an iis 7

Tags: iis-7, get, bots

on an iis7 machine, i am getting requests like these:

```
GET /scripts/){F.html(E o( 80 - 188.109.xxx.xxx Java/1.4.1_04
GET /scripts/]||!o.support.htmlSerialize&&[1, - 80 - 188.109.xxx.xxx Java/1.4.1_04
GET /scripts/);c.extend(this,{_aspectRatio:!!(j.aspectRatio),aspectRatio:j.aspectRatio,originalElement:this.element,_proportionallyResizeElements:[],_helper:j.helper||j.ghost||j.animate j.helper|| 80 - 188.109.xxx.xxx Java/1.4.1_04
GET /scripts/,e).html(j).prependTo(f);f.find( - 80 - 188.109.xxx.xxx Java/1.4.1_04
GET /scripts/,f.html()).html(g.spinner)}this.xhr=a.ajax(a.extend({},g.ajaxOptions,{url:d,success:function(i,h){a(c._sanitizeSelector(b.hash)).html(i);c._cleanup();if(g.cache){a.data(b, - 80 - 188.109.xxx.xxx Java/1.4.1_04
GET /scripts/,this.uiDialogTitlebar).html(f|| - 80 - 188.109.xxx.xxx Java/1.4.1_04
```

can i somehow deny access to these?

thanks.

Comment: What exactly are these requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IIS logs include remote IP address, you could stuff some REJECT or DENY or BLOCK rules into your system's firewall to drop them all on the floor before they reach IIS. I'd recommend aging them out of the firewall over time, because a lot of systems are on dynamic IPs, and you could wind up blocking access to legitimate users.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent bots (or humans for that matter) from attempting to access non-existant pages on your web server.